Omni Robot with ros_planar_move 4 wheels doesnt behave like omni robot
everyone.
I'm trying to enable navigation on a 4-wheel omni robot but it doesnt behave like expected, no y-linear velocity commands. I have tried all different controllers and planners to no effect. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is a video of the behaviour:
https://unlpt-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/lr_conceicao_fct_unl_pt/ETHHbVg7PT5BhWaAuitF7ugBcYS0Ax_-1NWtd_oLrnzAwQ?nav=eyJyZWZlcnJhbEluZm8iOnsicmVmZXJyYWxBcHAiOiJPbmVEcml2ZUZvckJ1c2luZXNzIiwicmVmZXJyYWxBcHBQbGF0Zm9ybSI6IldlYiIsInJlZmVycmFsTW9kZSI6InZpZXciLCJyZWZlcnJhbFZpZXciOiJNeUZpbGVzTGlua0NvcHkifX0&e=UoyEDh
amcl config:
amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    alpha1: 0.005
    alpha2: 0.005
    alpha3: 0.010
    alpha4: 0.005
    alpha5: 0.003
    base_frame_id: "base_footprint"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 100.0
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 60
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::OmniMotionModel" # omnidirectional nav2_amcl::OmniMotionModel
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_min_a: 0.2
    update_min_d: 0.25
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05
    scan_topic: scan

controller config:
ontroller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    controller_frequency: 50.0
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "nav2_mppi_controller::MPPIController"
      time_steps: 56
      model_dt: 0.09
      batch_size: 2000
      vx_std: 0.2
      vy_std: 0.2
      wz_std: 0.4
      vx_max: 0.5
      vx_min: -0.35
      vy_max: 1.0
      wz_max: 1.9
      iteration_count: 1
      prune_distance: 1.7
      transform_tolerance: 0.1
      temperature: 0.3
      gamma: 0.015
      motion_model: "Omni"
      visualize: false
      reset_period: 1.0 # (only in Humble)
      regenerate_noises: false
      TrajectoryVisualizer:
        trajectory_step: 5
        time_step: 3
      AckermannConstraints:
        min_turning_r: 0.0
      critics: ["GoalCritic", "PathAlignCritic", "PathFollowCritic", "ObstaclesCritic", "GoalAngleCritic", "PreferForwardCritic"]
      GoalCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 5.0
        threshold_to_consider: 1.4
      GoalAngleCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 3.0
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5
      PreferForwardCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 5.0
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5
      ObstaclesCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        repulsion_weight: 1.5
        critical_weight: 20.0
        consider_footprint: true
        collision_cost: 10000.0
        collision_margin_distance: 0.1
        near_goal_distance: 0.5
        inflation_radius: 0.55 # (only in Humble)
        cost_scaling_factor: 10.0 # (only in Humble)
      PathAlignCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 10.0
        max_path_occupancy_ratio: 0.07
        trajectory_point_step: 4
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5
        offset_from_furthest: 33
        use_path_orientations: false
      PathFollowCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 5.0
        offset_from_furthest: 6
        threshold_to_consider: 1.4

